# What easiest way to animate rigged 3d model of person?

Tags: animation, motion-capture

folks!

I'm alone creating a fitness app for mobile devices. And I need animated examples with workout exercises.
I bought rigged 3d models. But the problem is that I can't hire professional animators.

Doing animations by hands it's too long for me as an inexperienced at 3d animation guy.

Can I do animations with motion capturing with my iPhone and markers on different parts of the body? Or any similar way.

Comment: That's a question for the game engine you're using. Transfering data from iPhone to Blender will be a pain, and not just because it's Apple.

Comment: Motion capture devices require multiple cameras because more than 75% of the markers have to be recorded to have meaningful data. After motion captures are done, it's still not functional ... you still have to do manual motion cleanup for the captured data when some data are not recorded properly. So in short you are better off buying cleaned up motion data or hiring an animator for the job. There is a lot of work after buying motion data ... you need to know how to make sure the scale of the motion data fits the model ... and fix them, you will need a technical know how.